# Error while parsing XML in R

Tags: r, xml

I have some XML data which is as follows:

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<tasks xml=xyz.com/abc/wkbh/task>
<task>
<taskxml>
<Claim prDocumentIdentifier=137####_##62###>
<ClaimNumber>13####_##62###</ClaimNumber>
<FreeTextDescription>INS PASSENGER IN UNINSURED AUTOMOBILE THAT VEERED OFF THE RD INTO A DITCH</FreeTextDescription>
<ClaimCauses>
<ClaimCause>
<ActualValue>THIRD PARTY STRUCK INSURED'S PARKED VEHICLE</ActualValue>
<Category>MOTOR_ACCIDENT_TP_HIT_FP</Category>
</ClaimCause>
</ClaimCauses>
<IncidentDate>2006-10-13</IncidentDate>
<IncidentTime>14:30:00.000</IncidentTime>
<ReportedDate>2008-01-28</ReportedDate>
<ReportedTime>13:14:00.000</ReportedTime>
<ClosureDate>2014-06-25</ClosureDate>
<PolicyHolderDrivingAnotherVehicleFlag>N</PolicyHolderDrivingAnotherVehicleFlag>
<UnusualCircumstancesFlag>N</UnusualCircumstancesFlag>
<LiableParties>
<ActualValue>DRIVER NOT AT FAULT</ActualValue>
</LiableParties>
<ClaimType>
<Category>PERSONAL_MOTOR</Category>
</ClaimType>
<ClaimStatus>
<ActualValue>OPEN</ActualValue>
<Category>OPEN</Category>
</ClaimStatus>
<CloseReason>
<ActualValue>PAID</ActualValue>
<Category>SETTLED</Category>
</CloseReason>
<ClaimReportedBy>
<ActualValue>OTHER</ActualValue>
</ClaimReportedBy>
<SupportingInformation>
<AuthoritiesNotifiedOrAtScene>N</AuthoritiesNotifiedOrAtScene>
<UnusualCircumstances>N</UnusualCircumstances>
</SupportingInformation>
<ClaimSites>
<ClaimSite>
<IsOccupiedFlag>Y</IsOccupiedFlag>
</ClaimSite>
</ClaimSites>
<MotorClaimVehicles>
<MotorClaimVehicle>
<ID>104####_137####</ID>
<MotorClaimVehicleRole>
<ActualValue>POLICY_HOLDER_VEHICLE</ActualValue>
<Category>POLICY_HOLDER_VEHICLE</Category>
</MotorClaimVehicleRole>
<Make>FORD</Make>
<ManufactureYear>2002</ManufactureYear>
<Model>FOCUS SE WAGON</Model>
<Status>
<Category>ACTIVE</Category>
</Status>
<TotalDistanceTravelled>
<Units>KM</Units>
<Amount>0</Amount>
</TotalDistanceTravelled>
<OwnershipStatus>
<ActualValue>OWNED</ActualValue>
<Category>OWNED</Category>
</OwnershipStatus>
</MotorClaimVehicle>
</MotorClaimVehicles>
</Claim>
</taskxml>
</task>
</tasks>
```

I'm trying to extract the columns ClaimNumber, FreeTextDescription and others into a data frame. When I'm trying to parse the data using XML package

```
xml_df_task <- xmlParse("xyz.xml")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: 1: String not started expecting ' or "
2: Malformed declaration expecting version
3: Blank needed here
4: parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected
5: AttValue: " or ' expected
6: attributes construct error
7: Couldn't find end of Start Tag tasks line 1
8: Extra content at the end of the document
```

I am new to XML related packages. So any help around this error is highly appreciated.

P.S. This is only a small snippet of an actual column.

**Edit:** The XML is a valid one but it is embedded in some of the columns of the data which is in text format. When I'm trying to read the text data in R and convert to data frame using the code:

```
fpath <- "pathofdata.txt"
dat <- read.table(fpath, header = T, sep = "|", fill = T)
```

I'm getting a data frame but the XML content is becoming invalid as some of the quotes are vanishing. So, trying to parse it as a seperate XML after the data frame step is not working out.

An updated snippet of the data:

```
H|TASK_ID|TASK_REFERENCE|TASK_NAME|TASK_TYPE|TASK_RAISED_TS|TASK_STATE|TASK_VIEWED_FLAG|TASK_OUTCOME|CURRENT_QUEUE|QUEUE_CHANGE_TS|**TASK_XML_DATA**|**SCORE_XML_DATA**|
|"12"|"137####_##62###"|"137####_##62###"|"Claim"|"14APR2015:23:36:04"|"AwaitingTriageEast"|"N"|" "|"4"|"."|"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tasks xmlns="xyz.com/abc/wkbh/task">
```

.....
(same as above)

Any help on this error would save my day.

Comment: @amrrs don't spread misleading info when you know not what you speak of. `?xmlParse` : _"Parses an XML or HTML file or string containing XML/HTML content,…"_

Comment: @hrbrmstr Maybe i wasn't clear enough, please read the question it gives file name as a string which is what i meant, an XML formatted in the form of string would of course work! I thought it was obvious to understand and I definitely know what I'm talking about!

Comment: Others will have to take your word for it.

Comment: I've deleted mine! Thx!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
xml_doc <- read_xml("test.xml")

ClaimNumber <- xml_doc %>% 
  xml_find_all("//tasks/task/taskxml/Claim/ClaimNumber") %>% 
  xml_text()
FreeTextDescription <- xml_doc %>% 
  xml_find_all("//tasks/task/taskxml/Claim/FreeTextDescription") %>% 
  xml_text()
df <- data.frame(ClaimNumber, FreeTextDescription)
df
```

Output is:

```
      ClaimNumber                                                       FreeTextDescription
1 1376025_##62### INS PASSENGER IN UNINSURED AUTOMOBILE THAT VEERED OFF THE RD INTO A DITCH
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ Prem - The file is .txt as only 2 columns in the data have XML content. So, xml_doc <- read_xml("test.xml") will not work. I have edited my question to include that information.

Comment: This doesn't work because the file given in the OP isn't a valid XML file - it still gives a `String not started expecting ' or " [33]` error

Comment: @MikeStanley I had not seen the edited part by OP. But in order to run my code you just need to put `'` around namespace value in 2nd and 5th line of XML. (BTW - gentleman who downvoted it should explain the action)

Comment: @ Prem - The data snippet is a very small portion of an actual column and I have around 35k rows of data. Is there an automated way to put the quotes?

Comment: Maybe regex would be handy in this case - `xml_variable <-
 gsub("prDocumentIdentifier=", "prDocumentIdentifier='", "xml_variable")`; `xml_variable <- gsub("><ClaimNumber>", "'><ClaimNumber>", "xml_variable")`

Comment: @Debbie Just wondering if it solved your problem? If not then pls upload the sample file so that dots can be connected.

Comment: @ Prem - Your code is just opening the quotes by not closing them. And I guess I need to wrap any value which comes after "=" in the XML for it to run error free?

Comment: @ Prem - `df$xml_variable <- gsub("prDocumentIdentifier=", "prDocumentIdentifier='", df$xml_variable)` is giving me `<Claim prDocumentIdentifier='1370000_##62000>`. `df$xml_variable <- gsub("prDocumentIdentifier=", "prDocumentIdentifier='", "df$xml_variable")` is not working as it is replacing the entire column by the string `"df$xml_variable"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155144/discussion-between-prem-and-debbie).

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not valid.

The values of your attributes should be in quotes - that's what the `1: String not started expecting ' or "` and `5: AttValue: " or ' expected` means. You can see this if you paste your XML into any online XML validator.

In this case the unquoted `version` and `encoding` attributes on line 1 are causing the error but there are two more examples in your document - the `xml` attribute on line 2 and the `prDocumentIdentifier` on line 5.

See also: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp

---

This occurred because your source file, which is a delimited file with `|` as the separator, uses the `"` character to demarcate strings. But it also uses `"` inside those strings without escaping them, which will cause a parsing error of the type you're seeing, and create invalid XML. You need to fix the output of the file or use a different transport format.

Comment: @ Mike Stanley - Thanks for the response. I have edited my question to include additional information.

Comment: @Debbie Ok, I understand now - your problem isn't that your XML is invalid, your problem is that your source file is invalid. It can't use the " character as its string indicator and also use it unescaped inside the strings. That can't be parsed correctly. So your |-separated-values file isn't importable in its current state.